# Efficient pythonic way for this operation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am looking for an efficient way to perform the following operation; here is a minimal working code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

n = 7
m = 100
N = 3000

a = np.random.rand( n,m,N ) + np.random.rand( n,m,N )*1j
b = np.random.rand( n,m,N ) + np.random.rand( n,m,N )*1j

# we want product over the n-dimension, with fftconvolve in the m-indices elementwise

old_shape= a.shape 
new_shape= ( n*m, N )
    
a  = a.reshape( new_shape ) 

for i in range( n ):
    
    b_tiled = np.tile( b[ i, :, : ], ( n, 1, 1 )).reshape( new_shape )
    result  = ( fftconvolve( b_tiled, a, mode="same", axes=-1 ) ).reshape( old_shape )
    
    result  = result.sum( axis=0 )
```

The operation calculates the FFT of the two arrays in a product-like way in the first index ( so I am avoiding a double loop over the range(n) indices, using just one ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Reference implementation

I will start wrapping the operation in a function so that I can easily compare implementations

```py
def ref_impl(a,b):
    n,m,N = a.shape
    a  = a.reshape( m*n, N ) 
    ans = []
    for i in range( n ):
        b_tiled = np.tile( b[ i, :, : ], ( n, 1, 1 )).reshape( n*m, N )
        result  = ( fftconvolve( b_tiled, a, mode="same", axes=-1 ) ).reshape( n, m, N )
        ans.append(result.sum( axis=0 ))
    return np.array(ans);
```

##### Simplify sum of tiled array

Tile replicates one element, sum reduce all the elements in one axis.

Notice that `b_tiled` is constant in the first axis, you have some reshaping but everything is aligned, so the first `result[k] = fftconvolve(b[i,:,:], a[k, :, :])` so the second result can be calculated as

`result = sum(fftconvolve(b[i,:,:], a[k, :, :]) for k in range(n))`

Since fftconvolve is linear this can be written as

`result = fftconvolve(b[i,:,:], sum(a[k, :, :]for k in range(n)))`

And this form can be vectorised

```py
def impl1(a,b):
    n,m,N = a.shape
    ans = []
    for i in range( n ):
        result  = ( fftconvolve( b[i, :, :], a.sum(axis=0), mode="same", axes=-1 ) )
        ans.append(result)
    return np.array(ans);
```

##### Simplify stack of slices

Index takes one element in one axis, stack will construct an array with multiple elements, this operation can be replaced by a single vectorized operation

```py
def impl2(a,b):
    n,m,N = a.shape
    return ( fftconvolve( b, np.tile(a.sum(axis=0), (n, 1, 1)), mode="same", axes=-1 ) )
```

##### Complexity

The implementations proposed will use less scratch space, will get rid of the for loop and will do only one `fftconvolve` instead of `n`. In summary for large inputs it will run `n` times faster.